# determining e to the x in Java using limited features

Tags: java, if-statement, math, while-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to determine the value of e to the x, using basically if's and loop's.
(The formula goes e<sup>x</sup> = 1 + x/1! + x<sup>2</sup>/2! + x<sup>3</sup>/3! + ...)

I was able to detemine e, with the following code:

```
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please inform us a number of terms you want to calc: ");
        int i = input.nextInt();
        int n = 1;
        double e = 1;
        int counter = 1;
        long m = 1;

        while (n <= i)
        {
            while (counter <= n){
                {
                    m = m * counter;
                    counter++;

                }
            }
            e += 1 / (double) m;
            n++;
        }
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

I was hoping someone would be able to help, with this task.

Comment: Why not use `Math.exp`? Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: I have not run this code, but you seem to be indicating that it works? So what exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this works (which idk if it does), I think you need to think more about your question?

if you want to find e^x, finding e itself is useless because you already have a formula to find e^x given e and x...

e^x = 1 + x/1! + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ...
just set up a for loop and calculate the summation

```
double total = 0;
for (double i = 0; i < something; i++) {
    total += Math.pow(x, i) / factorial(i);
}
```

but this smells like hw so you're probably going to have to make the factorial and power methods yourself, I'm assuming...